# NHibernate: (one or zero) to (one or zero) mapping

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities, `Foo` and `Bar` like so:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual Guid FooID { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar MyBar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual Guid BarID { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo MyFoo { get; set; }
}
```

both of these entities can exist independently of each other, but on occasion they are related and when that happens I want to make sure they are linked in the persistence layer.

I want my tables to resemble this:

```
create table Foo (
    FooID int primary key,
    -- other stuff
);

create table Bar (
    BarID int primary key,
    FooID int null references Foo(FooID) on delete no action on update no action
);
```

...and for NHibernate to be able to create the relationship between them.

How would I map this (XML preferred)?

Comment: @JBNizet, have you considered reading my question before downvoting it?  That is not what I am asking for.

Comment: You're asking how to create a bidirectional OneToOne association mapped by a foreign key, which is what the linked documentation explains.

Comment: @JBNizet, specifically, where the relationship is loosely constrained on both sides.  That is not addressed in that documentation.

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to change not-null="true" to not-null="false". Really hard to guess. And even without guessing, you could at least have tried the documented mapping.

Comment: @JBNizet, Sarcasm and snarkiness are really not appreciated.  Why would I try something that states it's for OneToOne if I don't want OneToOne?  The relationship I am trying to define is a Zero-or-One to Zero-or-One; it may be obvious to you, but try googling on that term and your referenced documentation is inexplicably missing from the results.

Comment: Because you haven't found any other kind of association in the documentation and that since Hibernate maps objects to a database, it obviously has to support null references, and OneToOne is thus the closest to what you need. Especially if it has a configurable `not-null` attribute. Add that to the fact that a benevolent SO contributor with a gold hibernate badge tells you that a bidirectional OneToOne is what you need, but that you don't even imagine his answer might be correct and start a sarcasm war with him.

Comment: @JBNizet, perhaps you should read your own comments... At no point did you say that I needed a bidirectional OneToOne with nulls, instead you downvoted and pointed to a piece of documentation that did not describe what I was asking about, without further explanation.  If you had put that as an answer I doubt I'd be the only one to downvote it.

Comment: Do you really think I pasted a link to a random part of the documentation in order to lead you to a bad way? Now answer honestly to the following question: did you read the Hibernate documentation before asking your question?

Comment: Beginning to end?  Be realistic.  If you have time to do that, more power to you, but here I am working on a Sunday evening desperately trying to get this project working.  If a search doesn't find what I'm looking for, SO can help, and the next time someone looks for something the same way, they will not have to experience the pain I did.

Comment: Don't take the following as a sarcastic or offensive remark, but the fact that you didn't sufficiently learn to use Hibernate could very well be an explanation of why you need to work on a Sunday evening. You'll lose countless hours trying to make things work that you wouldn't lose if you started by learning how Hibernate works before using it in a real application. Hibernate is a complex beast, but knowing that toOne associations are nullable is a basic thing that you normally learn in the first day of a decent Hibernate training.

Comment: I can't argue that point; I will say I had to read that documentation you pointed out several times over and I was still scratching my head about it a bit.  I'm quite sure others will have the same sort of questions I have.  It shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: @JBNizet I find your attitude awful. You toss off a link introduced with a snarky comment and expect the person to sing your praises? Don't take this comment as sarcastic or offensive, but the fact that you didn't sufficiently learn to have basic courtesy could very well be an explanation of why you are misleading perfectly legitimate questioners despite your so special and shiny "gold hibernate badge". The whole world is ecstatic that you understand Hibernate so well (apparently after just your one day of "decent" training). But they're not so glad you're commenting on questions. Obviously.

Comment: @ErikE: If your courtesy consists in coming out of nowhere and insulting people you haven't ever talked with, I'll keep mine, thank you. I don't expect anyone to sing my praises. I expect developers to be able to read documentation, that's all. And I don't see how pointing someone to the relevant part of the documentation is misleading him. Plonk.

Comment: @JBNizet Actually I'm not as mad as I sound. I merely tried to match your tone! If you didn't like it, consider that you are looking at yourself in the mirror. You "came out of nowhere" and "insulted someone you hadn't ever talked with" yourself! Anyway, I wish you well and all that! Happy New Year. Merry Easter. Live long and prosper. But just because something is perfectly clear *to you* is no call for being condescending to an honest questioner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So @JBNizet, in his snarky and sarcastic way, pointed out that a Zero-or-One to Zero-or-One relationship is considered a nullable bidirectional One to One relationship as far as Hibernate and NHibernate are concerned; therefore, as per http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-bidirectional-121, the mapping would be like this:

```
<class name="Foo">
    <id name="FooID" column="FooID">
        <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="MyBar" property-ref="MyFoo" />
</class>

<class name="Bar">
    <id name="BarID" column="BarID">
        <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="MyFoo" column="FooID" unique="true" not-null="false" />
</class>
```

(...I think.  Edits with clarifications are welcome.)